# What is the entropy increase associated with the absorption and remission of solar radiation?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-radiation, entropy, thermal-radiation

The average solar irradiance over the Earth is 1361 W/m2 with a wavelength distribution given by Planck's law for a temperature of about 5778 K. Approximately, the same amount of radiation is re-emitted back to space in the form of reflected light, microwaves and infrared light, with a distribution similar to a Planck's law with 288 K.

**How could we calculate the entropy increase associated with this process of absorption and remission of electromagnetic radiation?**